# FileUpload.Has File always return false while inside updatepanel

Tags: asp.net

My FileUpload is inside UpdatePanel Ajax and always returns false.
what should I do?here is my code

```
 if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            string script2 = "alert(\"uploaded\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script2, true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should definitely post also the UpdatePanel`s ASPX markup, from this code snippet it is hard to tell what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem,This happens due to Update panel,The solution is to Store file into session whenever the post back occurs.[Here How I solved it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34224017/4910768)